# What Is Excel Formula To Fill T2 From T1 Data Directly?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What Is Excel Formula To Fill T2 From T1 Data Directly ? The Answer Should Not Be Like "=A1", please answer a new formula if you know?

[image]

Comment: *The Answer Should Not Be Like `=A1`* Why not?

Comment: I need something different formula which can be bring the data to T2 from T1 Vertical method

Comment: *I need something different* Well, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a variation is:

```
=IF(A1="","",A1)
```

Or if you expect a minimum value of 21 for example:

```
=IF(A1>=21,A1,0)
```

You could replace the 0 with "" ie blank.

Comment: Then you can drag down instead of across.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. I need something different formula which can be bring the data to T2 from T1 Vertical method. Please let me know more formulas for this.

Comment: hope you are telling me to copy+paste Special in Vertical method right? I knew it but i need though formula.

Comment: I have given you two versions, but without any further detail from you as to what you are trying to achieve and, perhaps more importantly, why then I am not sure what else to give you. Are you expecting a vba solution? Have you tried recording a macro to do what you want.?

Comment: I note you deleted your original comment to leave my reply "hanging out in the wind"...  And where did I suggest copy, paste special?